# How to add custom method to a angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework and I create a new directive to IonButton component, it actually disables the button and then enable it back when a process is completed (lets say it is a saving progress).

Here is my button template

```html
<ion-button fill="clear" color="primary" expand="block" (click)="acceptRequest()" [submitButton]="true">
    ACCEPT
</ion-button>
```

`[submitButton]` is an Input in my directive to enable the click listener.

I can disable the button and modify its content after click using a `@HostListener`,

```js
@HostListener('click') onButtonClick() {
const spinnerContent = `<ion-spinner name="dots"></ion-spinner>`
    if (this.isSubmitButton) {
        const spinnerContent = `<ion-spinner name="dots"></ion-spinner>`
        this.buttonElement.disabled = true;

        const btnChildren = this.el.nativeElement.children;
        this.oldElement = this.el.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);

        for (let child of btnChildren) {
          this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement, child);
        }
        this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = spinnerContent;
    }
}
```

The problem is how can I implement when to re-enable the button after the saving process is complete. I am saving the data inside `acceptRequest()` method using RxJS. Let's say I am saving to the API, and re-enable the button.

Some example I know is `IonRefresher`, we can easily call `event.target.complete()` to complete the loading spinner and hide the refresher from the page.

Thank you.

Edit:
I know that it is easier to use [disabled] inside the button instead of using directives, but I need to change the child nodes of the element, and can be used easily. So I think of using directive as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can viewChild the button, and cast it to the directive, while exposing an API on the directive to stop the spinner (and reenable everything you want).

in the directive, you add a function you want to expose, and then in your component, on the template, you add #myBtn:

```
<ion-button #myBtn fill="clear" color="primary" expand="block" (click)="acceptRequest()" [submitButton]="true">
    ACCEPT
</ion-button>
```

and in the component itself, you can cast the child to the directive:

```
@ViewChild("myBtn", { read: SubmitDirective }) myBtn: SubmitDirective;
```

and then, after you are done with your API call, you can call the function on the directive you just created (`this.myBtn.stopSpinner()`)

here is a new working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/access-directive-from-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I missed something in the question. On the host listener, it does not only disable the button, instead it changes the DOM inside the button, with spinner. I revised the question, hope you can help further ;). Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: It is working! Thank you for the answer. Upvoted.

Is there any alternative way to access those methods from the button event itself? Like the other ionic component where we can pass the event from template, and just execute `event.target.complete()` from there?

Comment: maybe you can create an output and return a subject, which you can then complete, I've never done it before, so can't really offer help on that (I mostly opt in to the option I gave in my answer)